# Skip fields on collection.find() not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm developing a report system in Node.JS and MongoDB
I'm trying to make a query to get some datas from the MongoDB, but the query don't specify all the fields that the collection have

(example, in the query I'm asking for the field `typ`, `event` and `date`, but in the collection I have more than 10 fields).

```
db.collection('logs').find({
    system: {
        type: query.logType,
        event: query.event,
        date: query.date
    }
}).toArray(function (err, document) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(document);
});
```

This way, it doesn't return anything, but when I specify all the fields that the collection have, the query works.

Is there any way to use RegEx or skip the other not-needed fields on the query?

Comment: can you please how your date looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use map and select properties in that function

```js
let tmp = [{id:1,name:"aaa"},{id:2,name:"bbb"}].map((item)=>{
    // your can make new object here
    return {name: item.name};
});
console.log(tmp);
```